# In telerik RadSpreadSheet how can I get cell name from cell index or selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, telerik, spreadsheet

```
private string GetCellName()
{
    var cell = mySpreadsheet.ActiveWorksheetEditor.Selection.ActiveCell;

    // I expect A1 if active cell is cell[0,0]
    return cell. // What should i call here to get cell name;
}
```

Using Telerik RadSpreadSheet in a WPF application
I'm trying to get cell reference (cell name like in excel application A1, B15, ...) from Selection object or a given cell index
**Note:**
[Telerik understand reference in formulas](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radspreadsheet-features-formulas-cell-references.html)
[there is a class called CellReference](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/allmembers_t_telerik_windows_documents_spreadsheet_model_cellreference.html)

Answer (score 2):

Class [NameConverter](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/allmembers_t_telerik_windows_documents_spreadsheet_utilities_nameconverter.html) provide helper methods to make conversion between cell or column index and names

```
private string GetCellName()
{
     CellIndex cellIndex = this.radSpreadsheet.ActiveWorksheetEditor.Selection.ActiveCellIndex;
     return NameConverter.ConvertCellIndexToName(cellIndex);
}
```